# Solve ugly color in ls command

Tags: zsh, ls, oh-my-zsh

I installed zsh + oh-my-zsh in an archlinux environment.
after that `ls` command's output became like this:

[image]

How I can change folders' color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "ugly" colors are caused by two things:

- The use of `ls`'s `--color` option
- Uncommon permissions (mode bits) of the files/directories that are displayed

Remedies:

- Adjust the colors to your taste by setting/changing the `LS_COLORS` environment variable (see [`ls`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), [`dircolors`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dircolors.1.html) and [`dir_colors`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/dir_colors.5.html) manpages)
- Fix your folder permissions (there is probably something fishy, like `o+w`); either `chmod` them, or change the `mount` option if `/d/archive` is a mount point for a filesystem that does not support file permissions (e.g. FAT/VFAT)
- Do not use the `color` option: `ls` is probably an alias to `ls --color=auto` (you can confirm this with `type ls`); either type `ls --color=never` to override it, or `unalias ls`, or modify your Zsh startup scripts to comment out the `ls` alias definition.

Comment: don't forget that oh-my-zsh already has theming for exactly that, and that the thing that actually decides as what color to display some terminal color is the terminal emulator, not the program run in the terminal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't know oh-my-zsh and if you think there is something to add the my answer, without changing its `ls`-centric content, then please do. As to who is deciding what color to display for a given file, it's `ls`, not the terminal. The terminal just gives you the liberty to define precisely what RGB is actually a red foreground, a blue background, etc. but nonetheless, this is `LS_COLORS` that instruct `ls` what generic color (red, blue, etc) to use for the foreground and the background for a given file/dir.

Comment: exactly. oh-my-zsh is a zsh script set that allows for  the difinition of *themes*, which set LS_COLORS. Since OP specifically tagged [tag:oh-my-zsh], they're using that feature and that will conflict with manually setting that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can't oh-my-zsh be customized? If you know how to set LS_COLORS the oh-my-zsh way, this would be worth adding to my answer.

Comment: yes, that's the whole point of it